# How to add something to edit summary when using Pywikibot?

Tags: mediawiki, pywikibot

I am using Pywikibot at this moment, to add a lot of files in a category, and the Edit summary looks like this: *"Bot: Adding category Taken with Sony DSC-WX350)"*

I would like to add the text *"using Pywikibot in automatic mode"*

How to do that?

Comment: do you use one of your own script, that you wrote, or do you use a buil-in one like `category` that is available with pywikibot ? In the second case, you should append `-summary:"Bot: Adding category using Pywikibot in automatic mode"` argument in your command line.

Comment: Please excuse me, I thought I answered your question but probably I closed the window before submitting it. I am using the pre-made script category.py. Thanks for your answer, I was using this option just as I've seen your answer.

Comment: Just a note: `-summary` parameter allows you to set a fixed summary, but you'll not be able to get something like `Bot: Adding category Taken with Sony DSC-WX350) using Pywikibot in automatic mode`, a text that varies. If you absolutely want to get this, you'll need to edit the code of `category.py` or create [an issue](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/project/view/87/) for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pywikibot.save` has a parameter `summary`

Comment: or simply `pywikibot.save('summary')`.