# How to create and or edit a page with pyWikiBot

Tags: python, pywikibot

The MediaWiki API has an [edit function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit/en) which is available within pywikibot.
According to https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.site.html

the function is called with a page parameter:

```
 editpage(page, summary=None, minor=True, notminor=False, bot=True, recreate=True, createonly=False, nocreate=False, watch=None, **kwargs)[source]¶
```

A page needs a source to be constructed. I could not find an example for this.

E.g.: [How to add something to edit summary when using Pywikibot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469124/how-to-add-something-to-edit-summary-when-using-pywikibot)

has just one line as the accepted answer and does not use site or page. I am confused.

**What is the proper approach do create and or edit a page with pyWikiBot directly using python code?** (not script ...)

[https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot/blob/master/pywikibot/page/**init**.py#L2328](https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot/blob/master/pywikibot/page/__init__.py#L2328)

has the constructor:

```
"""Page: A MediaWiki page."""

    @deprecated_args(defaultNamespace='ns', insite=None)
    def __init__(self, source, title='', ns=0):
        """Instantiate a Page object."""
        if isinstance(source, pywikibot.site.BaseSite):
            if not title:
                raise ValueError('Title must be specified and not empty '
                                 'if source is a Site.')
        super(Page, self).__init__(source, title, ns)
```

Which is unfortunately not properly documented and part of the 6000 line **init**.py file having all the classes.

When trying

```
    newPage=Page(site,pageTitle)
    newPage.text=pageContent
```

I get

```
AttributeError: APISite instance has no attribute 'edit'
    site.edit(newPage,'summary')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works:

```
 from pywikibot.page import Page

 newPage=Page(site,pageTitle)
 newPage.text=pageContent
 newPage.save("summary")
```

see also https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Create_your_own_script

It's just unfortunate that the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/pywikibot/ is not using standard python documentation tools.